# pass first img src from parsed feed to another elem's bg img property

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, essentially I'm parsing a few RSS feeds with jQuery. I want to grab the latest parsed **IMAGE** and take this latest *(or first instance)* `img src` and populate my second specified element's css `background-image:` property with it's contents. So, my first instance `img src` from my feed output, will also populate my second element's background-image with it's contents. I have been working with the below logic. But, I always get `background-image: 'undefined'` in the **console**.

*For some reason it's not reading or catching the first instance of populated image from first line below.*

```
 var HeadImg = $('.featimg img').first().attr('src'); // not pulling
 $('.site-featured-content').css('background-image', 'url(' + HeadImg + ')');
```

**Below is** my **full JS for context**.

*I have also tried moving the above two lines before and after rss feed JS.*

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 

  var url = window.location.href;

  if (url.indexOf('check') > -1) {  
      $(".feed1").rss("http://www.thehollywoodgossip.com/rss.xml",
      {
        limit: 17,
        entryTemplate:'<h1 class="feedtitle"><a href="{url}">[{author}@{date}] {title}</a></h1><br/><div class="featimg">{teaserImage}</div><div class="feedtxt">{shortBodyPlain}</div>'
      })
      $(".feed2").rss("http://www.thehollywoodgossip.com/rss.xml",
      {
        limit: 17,
        entryTemplate:'<h1 class="feedtitle"><a href="{url}">[{author}@{date}] {title}</a></h1><br/><div class="featimg">{teaserImage}</div><div class="feedtxt">{shortBodyPlain}</div>'
      })
      $(".feed3").rss("http://www.thehollywoodgossip.com/rss.xml",
      {
        limit: 17,
        entryTemplate:'<h1 class="feedtitle"><a href="{url}">[{author}@{date}] {title}</a></h1><br/><div class="featimg">{teaserImage}</div><div class="feedtxt">{shortBodyPlain}</div>'
      })
  }
  if (url.indexOf('movies') > -1) { 
      $(".feed1").rss("http://www.thehollywoodgossip.com/rss.xml",
      {
        limit: 17,
        entryTemplate:'<h1 class="feedtitle"><a href="{url}">[{author}@{date}] {title}</a></h1><br/><div class="featimg">{teaserImage}</div><div class="feedtxt">{shortBodyPlain}</div>'
      })
      $(".feed2").rss("http://www.thehollywoodgossip.com/rss.xml",
      {
        limit: 17,
        entryTemplate:'<h1 class="feedtitle"><a href="{url}">[{author}@{date}] {title}</a></h1><br/><div class="featimg">{teaserImage}</div><div class="feedtxt">{shortBodyPlain}</div>'
      })
      $(".feed3").rss("http://www.thehollywoodgossip.com/rss.xml",
      {
        limit: 17,
        entryTemplate:'<h1 class="feedtitle"><a href="{url}">[{author}@{date}] {title}</a></h1><br/><div class="featimg">{teaserImage}</div><div class="feedtxt">{shortBodyPlain}</div>'
      })
  }
  if (url.indexOf('host') > -1) { 
      $(".feed1").rss("http://www.dlisted.com/rss.xml",
      {
        limit: 17,
        entryTemplate:'<h1 class="feedtitle"><a href="{url}">[{author}@{date}] {title}</a></h1><br/><div class="featimg">{teaserImage}</div><div class="feedtxt">{shortBodyPlain}</div>'
      })
      $(".feed2").rss("http://stupidcelebrities.net/feed/",
      {
        limit: 17,
        entryTemplate:'<h1 class="feedtitle"><a href="{url}">[{author}@{date}] {title}</a></h1><br/><div class="featimg">{teaserImage}</div><div class="feedtxt">{shortBodyPlain}</div>'
      })
      $(".feed3").rss("http://www.thehollywoodgossip.com/rss.xml",
      {
        limit: 17,
        entryTemplate:'<h1 class="feedtitle"><a href="{url}">[{author}@{date}] {title}</a></h1><br/><div class="featimg">{teaserImage}</div><div class="feedtxt">{shortBodyPlain}</div>'
      })
  }
if (url.indexOf('TheCollegeLife') > -1) { 
      $(".feed1").rss("http://www.thehollywoodgossip.com/rss.xml",
      {
        limit: 17,
        entryTemplate:'<h1 class="feedtitle"><a href="{url}">[{author}@{date}] {title}</a></h1><br/><div class="featimg">{teaserImage}</div><div class="feedtxt">{shortBodyPlain}</div>'
      })
      $(".feed2").rss("http://www.thehollywoodgossip.com/rss.xml",
      {
        limit: 17,
        entryTemplate:'<h1 class="feedtitle"><a href="{url}">[{author}@{date}] {title}</a></h1><br/><div class="featimg">{teaserImage}</div><div class="feedtxt">{shortBodyPlain}</div>'
      })
      $(".feed3").rss("http://www.thehollywoodgossip.com/rss.xml",
      {
        limit: 17,
        entryTemplate:'<h1 class="feedtitle"><a href="{url}">[{author}@{date}] {title}</a></h1><br/><div class="featimg">{teaserImage}</div><div class="feedtxt">{shortBodyPlain}</div>'
      })
  }
  if (url.indexOf('WingmanConnect') > -1) { 
      $(".feed1").rss("http://www.thehollywoodgossip.com/rss.xml",
      {
        limit: 17,
        entryTemplate:'<h1 class="feedtitle"><a href="{url}">[{author}@{date}] {title}</a></h1><br/><div class="featimg">{teaserImage}</div><div class="feedtxt">{shortBodyPlain}</div>'
      })
      $(".feed2").rss("http://www.thehollywoodgossip.com/rss.xml",
      {
        limit: 17,
        entryTemplate:'<h1 class="feedtitle"><a href="{url}">[{author}@{date}] {title}</a></h1><br/><div class="featimg">{teaserImage}</div><div class="feedtxt">{shortBodyPlain}</div>'
      })
      $(".feed3").rss("http://www.thehollywoodgossip.com/rss.xml",
      {
        limit: 17,
        entryTemplate:'<h1 class="feedtitle"><a href="{url}">[{author}@{date}] {title}</a></h1><br/><div class="featimg">{teaserImage}</div><div class="feedtxt">{shortBodyPlain}</div>'
      })
  }
  if (url.indexOf('Media2point0') > -1) { 
      $(".feed1").rss("http://www.thehollywoodgossip.com/rss.xml",
      {
        limit: 17,
        entryTemplate:'<h1 class="feedtitle"><a href="{url}">[{author}@{date}] {title}</a></h1><br/><div class="featimg">{teaserImage}</div><div class="feedtxt">{shortBodyPlain}</div>'
      })
      $(".feed2").rss("http://www.thehollywoodgossip.com/rss.xml",
      {
        limit: 17,
        entryTemplate:'<h1 class="feedtitle"><a href="{url}">[{author}@{date}] {title}</a></h1><br/><div class="featimg">{teaserImage}</div><div class="feedtxt">{shortBodyPlain}</div>'
      })
      $(".feed3").rss("http://www.thehollywoodgossip.com/rss.xml",
      {
        limit: 17,
        entryTemplate:'<h1 class="feedtitle"><a href="{url}">[{author}@{date}] {title}</a></h1><br/><div class="featimg">{teaserImage}</div><div class="feedtxt">{shortBodyPlain}</div>'
      })
  }
  if (url.indexOf('Brokepoint') > -1) { 
      $(".feed1").rss("http://www.thehollywoodgossip.com/rss.xml",
      {
        limit: 17,
        entryTemplate:'<h1 class="feedtitle"><a href="{url}">[{author}@{date}] {title}</a></h1><br/><div class="featimg">{teaserImage}</div><div class="feedtxt">{shortBodyPlain}</div>'
      })
      $(".feed2").rss("http://www.thehollywoodgossip.com/rss.xml",
      {
        limit: 17,
        entryTemplate:'<h1 class="feedtitle"><a href="{url}">[{author}@{date}] {title}</a></h1><br/><div class="featimg">{teaserImage}</div><div class="feedtxt">{shortBodyPlain}</div>'
      })
      $(".feed3").rss("http://www.thehollywoodgossip.com/rss.xml",
      {
        limit: 17,
        entryTemplate:'<h1 class="feedtitle"><a href="{url}">[{author}@{date}] {title}</a></h1><br/><div class="featimg">{teaserImage}</div><div class="feedtxt">{shortBodyPlain}</div>'
       })
    }
    var HeadImg = $('.featimg img').first().attr('src');
    $('.site-featured-content').css('background-image', 'url(' + HeadImg + ')');
})
```

---

**Note://** Yes, `<div class="featimg">{teaserImage}</div>` renders as `<div class="featimg"><img class="class" src="/img.jpg"></div>`

Comment: You seem to be using some templating system. So you might be trying to access the `img` before it has been injected in the html.

Comment: I suggest to using a timeout. You can test if it works on debug mode or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as suggested:

```
function waitForCompleteRender()
{
    var HeadImg = $('.featimg img').first();
    if (HeadImg.length == 0) return setTimeout(waitForCompleteRender, 200);

    $('.site-featured-content').css('background-image', 'url(' + HeadImg.attr('src') + ')');

}

waitForCompleteRender();
```

**EDIT**

Please mind that this approach is pretty risky for production use (if the image is not rendered at all). You may want to add an *if statement* which will handle errors after X times with no success....